# Mixing imports of specific classes of different files in the same statement in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have statements like this in my script:

```
from com.example.project.fileA import ClassA
from com.example.project.fileB import ClassB
from com.example.project.fileC import ClassC
```

However, it's a bit tedious to repeat the parent path (com.example.project) in each import statement.

Is there a way to make this easier? I've already tried things like this:

```
from com.example.project import fileA.ClassA, fileB.ClassB, fileC.classC
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place the imports in the `__init__.py` file of your `project` module. For example, considering the following folder structure:

```
com/
  example/
    project/
      __init__.py
      fileA.py
      fileB.py
      fileC.py
my_code/
  my_script.py
```

You write the following in `com/example/project/__init__.py`:

```
from com.example.project.fileA import ClassA
from com.example.project.fileB import ClassB
from com.example.project.fileC import ClassC
```

Then from `my_script.py`, you can write:

```
from com.example.project import ClassA, ClassB, ClassC
```

This of course assumes that your current working directory is the project root folder (i.e. the folder containing both the `com` and `my_code` folders), which is the default when working with properly-structured projects in PyCharm, or when your project has been installed in editable mode (`pip install -e .`).

Comment: That seems a great solution! But just right now I was thinking about versioning this project as a module in github that I'd import to my other projects with pip. Is it still possible to have that solution in this scenario or does pip ignore init files?

Comment: It works just the same. For example, look at the [pandas source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/main/pandas/__init__.py): in `pandas/__init__.py` there is an import statement `from pandas.core.api import DataFrame`. Which is why once you `pip install pandas`, you can write `from pandas import DataFrame`, instead of having to import it all the way from `pandas.core.api`.